# Convert to E164 only if possible?

Tags: libphonenumber

Can I determine if the user entered a phone number that can be safely formatted into E164?

For Germany, this requires that the user started his entry with a local area code. For example, `123456` may be a subscriber number in his city, but it cannot be formatted into E164, because we don't know his local area code. Then I would like to keep the entry as it is. In contrast, the input `089123456` is independent of the area code and could be formatted into E164, because we know he's from Germany and we could convert this into `+4989123456`.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply convert your number into E164 using [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)
and after conversion checks if both the strings are same or not. If they're same means a number can not be formatted, otherwise the number you'll get from library will be formatted in E164.

Here's how you can convert

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
String formattedNumber = phoneUtil.format(inputNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
```

Finally compare **formattedNumber** with **inputNumber**

Comment: I don't think this is correct, or it at least misunderstands the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you'll need to play with `isValidNumber` and `isPossibleNumber` for your case. `format` is certainly not guaranteed to give you something actually dialable, see the [javadocs](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.java#L1052). This is suggested by the [demo](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html) as well, where formatting is not displayed when `isValidNumber` is false.

I also am dealing with this FWIW. In the context of US numbers: The issue is I'd like to parse using `isPossibleNumber` in order to be as lenient as possible, and store the number in E164. However then we accept, e.g. `+15551212`. This string itself even passes `isPossibleNumber` despite clearly (I think) not being dialable anywhere.